# Mostrar list<> en tabla de html con asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Quiero saber si se puede imprimir los datos de un list<> en una table de html o si es necesario imprimirlos en un gridview

```
namespace tts
{
    public class tabla_conexion
    {
        public DataTable connect()
        {
            string myConnectionString = @"C:\\Users\\gutiece\\Desktop\\database\\" + "Database1.accdb";

            DataTable SBTable = new DataTable();

            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
                bool ok = System.IO.File.Exists(myConnectionString);
                String qry = "SELECT * FROM information_tool_gen";
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = qry;

                adapter.SelectCommand = command;

                command.Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                List<tabla> Resultado = new List<tabla>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Resultado.Add(new tabla(
                        int.Parse(reader["id_global"].ToString()),
                        int.Parse(reader["torque"].ToString()),
                        int.Parse(reader["tol"].ToString()),
                        reader["um"].ToString(),
                        reader["module"].ToString(),
                        reader["batteries"].ToString(),
                        reader["torquemeter"].ToString(),
                        int.Parse(reader["frequency"].ToString()),
                        DateTime.Parse(reader["maint_date"].ToString()),
                        int.Parse(reader["status_id"].ToString()),
                        DateTime.Parse(reader["reg_date"].ToString())
                        ));
                }
                if (!reader.IsClosed)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
                return SBTable;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return SBTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Tengo una clase donde hago el get y el set de los datos

```
namespace tts
{
    public class tabla
    {
        public int ID_GLOBAL { get; set; }
        public int TORQUE { get; set; }
        public int TOL { get; set; }
        public String UM { get; set; }
        public String MODULE { get; set; }
        public String BATTERIES { get; set; }
        public String TORQUEMETER { get; set; }
        public int FREQUENCY { get; set; }
        public DateTime MAINT_DATE { get; set; }
        public int STATUS_ID { get; set; }
        public DateTime REG_DATE { get; set; }

        public tabla(
            int id_global,
            int torque,
            int tol,
            String um,
            String module,
            String batteries,
            String torquemeter,
            int frequency,
            DateTime maint_date,
            int status_id,
            DateTime reg_date
            )
        {
            this.ID_GLOBAL = id_global;
            this.TORQUE = torque;
            this.TOL = tol;
            this.UM = um;
            this.MODULE = module;
            this.BATTERIES = batteries;
            this.TORQUEMETER = torquemeter;
            this.FREQUENCY = frequency;
            this.MAINT_DATE = maint_date;
            this.STATUS_ID = status_id;
            this.REG_DATE = reg_date;
        }
        private tabla() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola César, la respuesta a tu pregunta es `sí`, se pueden imprimir en pantalla tanto por HTML como por `GridView`, la respuesta dependerá de cuál deseas usar.

Comment: Quieto usar una tabla hecha con html ya que quiero usar bootstrap

Answer (score 1):

Yo en tu caso, utilizaría un control Repeater, algo como lo siguiente:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptTable" runat="server" ItemType="tts.tabla">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Columna 1</th>
                    <th>Columna 2</th>
                    <th>Columna 3</th>
                    <th>Columna 4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td><%# Item.Columna1 %></td>
                    <td><%# Item.Columna2 %></td>
                    <td><%# Item.Columna3 %></td>
                    <td><%# Item.Columna4 %></td>
                </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

De esta forma en tu página al final tendrás exactamente lo que escribas dentro del Repeater en este caso lo que obtendrías en tu página HTML es una tabla como la siguiente:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Columna 1</th>
            <th>Columna 2</th>
            <th>Columna 3</th>
            <th>Columna 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Valor Columna1</td>
            <td>Valor Columna2</td>
            <td>Valor Columna3</td>
            <td>Valor Columna4</td>
        </tr>
        ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Revisando otros ejemplos mira tendrías que utilizar un método como este, para generar el HTML puro y ponerlo en la tabla:

```
public static string GetMyTable(IEnumerable list, params string[] columns)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        //todo this should actually make an HTML table, not just get the properties requested
        foreach (var column in columns)
            sb.Append(item.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(item, null));
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Lamarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
string htmlTable = GetMyTable(Resultado, "Columna1", "Columna2");//Los nombres de tu columnas separados por comas
```

Después asignar el `htmlTable` a un `div` de tu pagina `ASP`:

- Crear un `div` en tu código `aspx`:

  ```
   <div runat="server" id="divTabla">
   </div>
  ```
- Asignarle la tabla al `div`:

  ```
   divTabla.InnerHtml = htmlTable;
  ```

Otra forma de hacerlo, igual sin utilizar `gridView`... podrías utilizar `jquery` y el componente `jqueryDataTables`.

[Jquery.Datatables](https://datatables.net)

En este caso tendrías que seguir mas o menos estos paso:

1. Crear el metodo en codeBehind que retorne un JSON
2. Utilizar `Ajax` desde lado del cliente, con `jquery` para llamar a dicho método
3. Asignarle el `dataSource` con `jqueryDataTables`

Al utilizar **jquery.DataTables**, tienes de ventaja la tabla no será una *tabla simple y plana*, sino que puede tener paginador, modo edición, ordenar, búsqueda, etc., entre otras ventajas y propiedades que tiene este componente.