# Error list<> en gridview con foreach

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp

Queria saber como puedo mostrar los datos en un gridview, se que tengo que retornar la lista pero no encuentro como, se que debe ser facil pero **apenas estoy empezando con c#**

```
            DataTable SBTable = new DataTable();

            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

            try
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
                bool ok = System.IO.File.Exists(myConnectionString);
                String qry = "SELECT * FROM information_tool_gen";
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText = qry;

                adapter.SelectCommand = command;

                command.Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                List<tabla> Resultado = new List<tabla>();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Resultado.Add(new tabla(
                        int.Parse(reader["id_global"].ToString()),
                        int.Parse(reader["torque"].ToString()),
                        int.Parse(reader["tol"].ToString()),
                        reader["um"].ToString(),
                        reader["module"].ToString(),
                        reader["batteries"].ToString(),
                        reader["torquemeter"].ToString(),
                        int.Parse(reader["frequency"].ToString()),
                        DateTime.Parse(reader["maint_date"].ToString()),
                        int.Parse(reader["status_id"].ToString()),
                        DateTime.Parse(reader["reg_date"].ToString())
                        ));
                }

                List<tabla> lista = Resultado();
                {
                    foreach (var dato in lista)
                    {
                        DataGridView row = (DataGridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[0].clone();
                        row.cells["id_global"].value = var.id_global;
                        row.cells["torque"].value = var.id_global;
                        row.cells["tol"].value = var.tol;
                        row.cells["um"].value = var.um;
                        row.cells["module"].value = var.module;
                        row.cells["batteries"].value = var.batteries;
                        row.cells["torquemeter"].value = var.torquemeter;
                        row.cells["frequency"].value = var.frequency;
                        row.cells["maint_date"].value = var.maint_date;
                        row.cells["status_id"].value = var.status_id;
                        row.cells["reg_date"].value = var.reg_date;

                        GridView1.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
                if (!reader.IsClosed)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return SBTable;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Podrias aclarar sí ocupas devolver un DataTable, List<tabla> o sí preguntas como agregar al GridView los objetos de Resultado.

Comment: Mi pregunta es como agregar al GridView los objetos del resultado

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos, ya recibiste una [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/67254/78) en tu pregunta anterior - que es muy parecida. ¿Ya intentaste hacer lo siguiente `DataTable tbl = connect(); GridView1.DataSource = tbl; GridView1.DataBind();`?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave lo he intentado pero me marca error al momento de poner el nombre de mi `GridView`

Comment: @CesarGutierrezDavalos, **[edit] tu pregunta con la descripción del error** que tengas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buenos días, a lo que puedo ver, tienes una lista de objetos tipo *tabla* y si te entiendo bien, quieres retornar esta lista y que después se agregue a un `GridView`.

Aquí te dejo el código que deberías implementar para lograr el cometido.

```
//viene el resto de tu código
List<tabla> lista = tuMetodoqueRetornaLista();
foreach(var dato in lista)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)yourDataGridView.Rows[0].Clone();
    row.Cells["Columna1"].Value = var.dato1;
    row.Cells["Columna1"].Value = var.dato2;
    //agregas todos los campos
    yourDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Ahora bien, sí quieres hacerlo de una manera más sencilla, puedes desde la consulta pasar el `OleDbDataReader` a un `DataTable` y de ahí pasarlo a un `GridView`

```
        DataTable SBTable = new DataTable();

        OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DataSet dataset = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data source= " + myConnectionString;
            bool ok = System.IO.File.Exists(myConnectionString);
            String qry = "SELECT * FROM information_tool_gen";
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandText = qry;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;

            command.Connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            SBTable.Load(reader);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return SBTable;
    }
}
```

}

Ahora bien, en la parte de tu GridView, lo que debes hacer es lo siguiente:

```
DataTable dataTable = FuncionDevuelveTabla();
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
   yourDataGridView.DataSource = dataTable;
   yourDataGridView.DataBind();
}
else
{
   yourDataGridView.DataBind();       
}
```

Comment: el primer codigo lo deberia de poner en vez del return?

y la segunda opcion lo puse antes del ````OleDbReader```` y me marco error

Comment: Primero que todo sí vas a mostrar datos en un GridView, no necesitas del List<tabla> sí vas a retornar un DataTable. voy a modificar mi respuesta, para que te quede claro

Comment: En la parte del GridView te refieres al que se inserta en el html? (DIOS! Me estoy complicando y debe ser algo muy sencillo)

Comment: Todo esto es en el Code Behind

Comment: Realice el siguiente codigo ¿Es correcto?
`}
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
            return SBTable;
        }
    }
    
    protected void MuestraLista(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            DataTable dataTable = connect();
            if (SBTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DVTools.DataSource = dataTable;
                    DVTools.DataBind();
                }
                else
                {
                    DVTools.DataBind();       
                }
        }`